# Почему после vagrant up не запускается апач?

Tags: php, linux, vagrant

Установил Vagrant 1.7.4 и VirtualBox 4.3.30.
Скачал стандартную конфигурацию на PUPHPET залил в корень проекта.
Затем выполнил:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Выдало

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 7528 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => C:/var/www/awesome
    default: /vagrant => C:/var/www/awesome
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0376b8330ae31fddae2037df5d1ac019 => C:/var/www/awesome/puphpet/puppet/modules
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-893fcda21077f5a583c2dbbba8515c0a => C:/var/www/awesome/puphpet/puppet
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20150908-3840-1rzadud.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running files in files/startup-once
==> default: Finished running files in files/startup-once
==> default: To run again, delete hashes you want rerun in /.puphpet-stuff/startup-once-ran or the whole file to rerun all
==> default: Running files in files/startup-always
==> default: Finished running files in files/startup-always
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20150908-3840-s43tfk.sh
==> default: Running files in files/startup-once-unprivileged
==> default: Finished running files in files/startup-once-unprivileged
==> default: To run again, delete hashes you want rerun in /.puphpet-stuff/startup-once-unprivileged-ran or the whole file to rerun all
==> default: Running files in files/startup-always-unprivileged
==> default: Finished running files in files/startup-always-unprivileged

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Вагрант запущен. Затем пишу 
    sudo netstat -tlnp

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2470/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2470/sshd
```

И всё. Больше ничего нет. Я так понял должен показываться порт 80 еще и написано apach (ну и mysql и другие). Но эти процессы не запущены и я не могу понять в чём проблема.

Прописал в hosts.txt

```
192.168.56.101     awesome.dev
```

Папка с проектом лежит тут

```
C:/var/www/awesome
```

Стандартная конфигурация PUPHPET по умолчанию:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: local.puphpet
        memory: '512'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                vflnp_gl55a2aw5lrf:
                    host: '7528'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: 'on'
                showgui: '0'
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_shoe85q8o3fx:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: ''
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_8ctnqnmjskzx:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_k0qofaz8oi64:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'off'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                nxvl_8x67ehivanbi:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'off'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_2tseiksh6ngy:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_cucnv0nhzz0o:
                    path: /var/www/awesome
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_77e1wcxt8cbh:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_k377mr2ksl5w:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_2h2acjqs6aj2:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_qw9jwqjwqmu0:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_5zs54z0i0r9k:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.0'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_zrkcp9mz35aj:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_i6vygdr4ve2u:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_h6wsbeor5fg4:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.3'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Сайт не доступен и не открывается. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Дело в том, что при первой установке PUPHPET нужно юзать команду

```
vagrant up    
vagrant provision
```

Только теперь Vagrant применит конфигурацию для поднятого виртуального окружения, потому что команда vagrant up только поднимает окружение но не настраивает его.  Каждый раз когда виртуальное окружение будет меняться необходимо будет выполнять:

```
vagrant provision
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю почему, но у меня команда

```
vagrant provision
```

Ничего не подгружала окружение. Общие папки так и не синхронизировались. Эту проблему решила команда:

```
vagrant reload
```